# how to estimate the lognormal distribution 3 parameters using maximum lq likelihood method in R/Rstudio

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution

i've tried to find the equation for lq likelihood equation is:

- lq_likelihood <- ((f^(1-q))-1)/(1-q) and with f is pdf of lognormal distribution and q is distortion parameter(i'm using q=1-(1/n))
- define u <- logf(x) u' is first derivative of each parameter
- the first derivation of lq_likelihood: sum (f^(1-q) * u')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.